# View Database Tables From AWS in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench

I have successfully migrated my mysql database file to an aws mysql instance using MySQL Workbench.

I now want to test that everything is migrated properly. When I connect to the db using MySQL Workbench and run an sql query such as

```
SELECT * FROM Users
```

I get an error saying that no database has been selected. I'm thinking that I'm actually only connected to the server and not the actual database. Is there a method to connect to the actual db and view all the tables on the server using MySQL Workbench or possibly another tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never connect to a database. A database (aka schema) is just an organizational construct within a database server (aka RDBMS). So, first you connect to that server, to establish the communication. Then you select a schema to work with. Either run a USE command or, in MySQL Workbench, double click on a schema node in the schema tree on the left hand side to make this the current default. You can also set an initial default schema in the connection settings. The current (default) schema is shown in bold in the tree:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

There is a small expand button in the navigator panel on the left which can be expanded and I can view all my tables, columns etc...